# how to remove duplicates from all sheets in dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe with number of sheets,i wants to delete duplicate from all sheets.i used below code

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Month',keep='last')
```

after that i save this df

```
df.to_excel(path,index=False)
```

but its removing only 1st sheet duplicate and showing only one sheet

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest treating each sheet of your document as an separate data frame, then in iteration remove the duplicates of each set according to your criteria. This is quick draft of concept I had on mind, for 2 sheets:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('myFile.xls')
xls_dfs = []
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
xls_dfs.append(df1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
xls_dfs.append(df2)
for df in xls_dfs:
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Month',keep='last')
    df.to_excel('myFile.xls',index=False)
```

Comment: Still its not working,its giving only one sheet output